# Call to a member function givePermissionTo() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Spatie Laravel Permission Package. When trying to insert data to **models has permissions** table it gives the below error in postman. I don't know clearly how to insert data. I used the guide of spatie documentation.

error,

**Call to a member function givePermissionTo() on null**

here is my controller function

```
public function models()
    {
        
        Role::create(['name'=>'writer']);
        Permission::create(['name'=>'edit post']);

        Auth::id()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
       
        return 'hello';
    }
```

I don't know if the question is clear enough. Please tell me if it's not clear.

Comment: The error says that `Auth::id()` is _null_, meaning you're most likely not authenticated

Comment: That was the error. But I used   `auth()->user()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');` instead of  `Auth::id()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');`  then  `$this->middleware('auth');`  called in __construct function. Then issue fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Auth::id() return the id of the authenticated user, but you need to call givePermissionTo on a user object, not a user id.
try

```
Auth::user()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

Comment: Yes, that's also working. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

@brombeer was right. the issue was in the `Auth::id()` It says the authenticated user is not accessed in.
I changed my function line `Auth::id()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');` to `auth()->user()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');`. Also the called __construct() function like this,

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Then I accessed as an authorized user and inserted log in the token as a bearer token in postman. Then the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::id` returns the id of the user. The method `givePermissionTo` should be called on an object of the user and not the id.

**Here are two ways you can do it:**

**Method 1**

```
Auth::user()->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

**Method 2**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles);
```